# Setting path variable - java & C

Tags: java, c, classpath

Okay I need both java and C compilers to work on my pc.

So I have set the path variable of C and now I need to set java's path, so for that can I set the path variable of java in the same `PATH` (where I set path for C) or do I need to create a separate `PATH` for setting it up? Some one please help.

If I set both in a same path, then will anything go wrong? Sorry I am new to this, please bear with me. Thanks

Comment: Unless your system is different than what I'm used to, the PATH is just a semicolon separated list of paths so you should just need to add both to the one global PATH.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about generic OS functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would matter if there were any name collisions. To my knowledge there's no such, but since there are many C compilers and much more stuff for them, and the most important java stuff starts with 'java', just add the Java path AFTER the gcc/mingw path

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;%MINGW_PATH%\bin;%JAVA_PATH%\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am introducing you to what is `PATH` variable ?

PATH is an environment variable on Unix-like operating systems, DOS, OS/2, and Microsoft Windows, specifying a set of directories where executable programs are located. In general, each executing process or user session has its own PATH setting.

*On POSIX and Unix-like operating systems, the $PATH variable is specified as a list of one or more directory names separated by **colon (:)** characters*

*On DOS, OS/2, and Windows operating systems, the %PATH% variable is specified as a list of one or more directory names separated by **semicolon (;)** characters.[3]*

Note : The above is an excerpt from [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)

For Windows, you can set the path

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;%MINGW_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

For Unix-like operating systems, you can do

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;\home\%MINGW_HOME%\bin;\home\%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```